# Array of <img> tags passing to initialPreview property

Tags: javascript, c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In the following  function's `initialPreview` property I want load array of `<img>` tags. For that I'm creating

```
$("#id").fileinput({
        .......,
        initialPreview: [ getFiles() ],
    });
```

I just created `getFiles()` method as follows

```
$(document).ready(function getFiles() {
var files = [];

$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: '@Url.Action("filesinfolder", "Home")',
dataType: "json",
success: function (data) {

$.each(data, function (index, item) {    
   files.push(img.get(0));
   return files;    
});},

error: function (xhr, status, err) {
}
});
});
```

then I wrote following server side method to get files

```
     public JsonResult filesinfolder(string productid,ProductEdit model)
    {
        productid = "01";

        string salesFTPPath = "C:/Users/user/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/rootProject/project_name/project_name/Content/Essential_Folder/marketing_materials_EN/01";
        DirectoryInfo salesFTPDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(salesFTPPath);
        IEnumerable<string> files = salesFTPDirectory.GetFiles()
          .Where(f => f.Extension == ".xls" || f.Extension == ".xml" || f.Extension == ".jps" || f.Extension == ".jpg" || f.Extension == ".jpeg" || f.Extension == ".png" || f.Extension == ".PNG")
          .OrderBy(f => f.Name)
          .Select(f => f.Name);

        // build urls
        model.ImageUrls = new List<string>();

        foreach (string name in files)
        {
            model.ImageUrls.Add(Url.Content("~/Content/Essential_Folder/marketing_materials_EN/" + productid) + "/" + name);
        }

        return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

once I debug in server code I can see the model as follows

[image]

But here I don't know how to push those URLs to array inside  `getFiles()`
success event.

Actually I want to get `initialPreview` values as follows

`initialPreview:[ 
"<img src='http://localhost:49669/Content/Essential_Folder/marketing_materials_EN/Image1.jpg'>",
"<img src='http://localhost:49669/Content/Essential_Folder/marketing_materials_EN/Image2.jpg''>",
  ....],`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `ImageUrls` property (which is an array) of the data coming back from your server call.

```
success: function (data) {

  $.each(data.ImageUrls, function (index, item) {    
     files.push(item));         
  });
},
```

Also if you want to return an array of image urls from your `getFiles()` method, you do not need to define it inside `document.ready` event. You can define it outside. Also you may consider using the [getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) method which is basically shorthand ajax call with `dataType:'json'`

```
$(function(){
   //Call some method as need (ex:initializing some plugin ,add some event handlers etc.)
});

function getFiles() {
   var files = [];
   var myUrl = '@Url.Action("filesinfolder", "Home")';

   $.getJSON(myUrl ,function(data){

      $.each(data.ImageUrls, function (index, item) {    
         files.push(item));         
      });

   });     
   return files;
}
```

Also, if you want to pass the array to the `initialPreview` property , just call the `getFiles()` method. Do not need to use the [] around that. Since ajax is asynchronous, i would recommend calling the getFiles() method first and then calling passing that to wherever you need.

```
$(function(){

   var urlsArray=getFiles();
   $("#id").fileinput({
     //existing code 
      initialPreview: urlsArray,
     //existing code 
   });

});
```

Comment: Actually I want to get `initialPreview` values as follows `initialPreview: [
    "<img src='/Content/Essential_Folder/marketing_materials_EN/Image1.jpg'>",
    "<img src='/Content/Essential_Folder/marketing_materials_EN/Image2.jpg''>",....],` , so is this possible to do ?

Comment: I just changed as you said just [look at this](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/q8KGy) but its not load files to fileinput

Comment: does this `$.each(data.ImageUrls..` should be inside the `success: function` ?

Comment: getJSON's call back is basically the shorthand to the success event of ajax call. It should be good.

Comment: bit correction here, Actually I want to get `initialPreview` values as follows

`initialPreview:[ 
"<img src='http://localhost:49669/Content/Essential_Folder/marketing_materials_EN/Image1.jpg'>",
"<img src='http://localhost:49669/Content/Essential_Folder/marketing_materials_EN/Image2.jpg''>",
  ....],`

Comment: That looks like an array and that is exactly what your getFiles() also returns.

Answer (score 0):

You can change little bit code and then you can get desire output

```
success: function (data) {
        $.getJSON(myUrl ,function(data){
            $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                var img = $('<img>').attr('src', item); 
                files.push(img.outerHTML());
            });
            return files;
        });
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my Answer , want load

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    url: '@Url.Action("filesinfolder", "Home")',
    success: function (data) {
       $("#id").fileinput({
       .......,
       initialPreview: data,
       });
    }
  })
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.